# The same result using sum and case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, case

I have the following query but it produces the same result, the result should be different

```
select 
COALESCE(Clinic,'total') as Clinic,
sum(Revenue/ND) as Revenue_ND,
sum(Revenue/Home_Care) as Revenue_Home_Care
from
(
   select
   businesses.label as Clinic,
   COUNT(CASE 
    WHEN appointment_types.name like '%initial%' and appointment_types.category IN (
        'National- Ex Phys- ND',
        'National- Physio -ND',
        'National- OT -ND',
        'National- Speech Pathology- ND',
        'SA/WA - Physiotherapy - ND',
        'SA/WA - Telehealth Physiotherapy - ND'
    ) then 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    as ND,
   COUNT(CASE 
    WHEN appointment_types.name like '%initial%' and appointment_types.category IN (
        'National- Zest',
        'National- OT -HCP',
        'National- Physio -HCP',
        'National- Physio -Remedy',
        'National-Physio-TUH',
        'National- Speech Pathology- HCP'
    ) then 1 ELSE 0 END)
    as Home_Care,
  sum(CASE 
    WHEN appointment_types.category is not null 
    then invoices.net_amount ELSE 0 END)
    as Revenue
FROM 
  individual_appointments
  INNER join appointment_types on
  appointment_types.id = individual_appointments.appointment_type_id
  inner join invoices on
  invoices.appointment_id = individual_appointments.id
  inner join businesses on
  businesses.id = individual_appointments.business_id
WHERE
  {{clinic}} 
  and {{date}}
group by 
  businesses.label
)x
group by 
  ROLLUP(Clinic);
```

Result :

```
 Clinic                   Revenue_ND             Revenue_Home_Care
 Marli                    51.33                    51.33
 Alexandria               94.21                    94.21
 total                    230.48                   230.48
```

it should result in a different column value.
Can you show me where the error is and the correct query solution?

Answer (score 0):

The original version of the question was tagged MySQL.

`COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values of the condition.  In your code, the `CASE` expression is returning `1` or `0`.  And neither of these are `NULL`.

MySQL has a convenient shortcut for this type of counting, one that needs no conditional logic.  You can just add up the boolean values:

```
SUM( appointment_types.name like '%initial%' and 
     appointment_types.category IN (
     'National- Ex Phys- ND',
     'National- Physio -ND',
     'National- OT -ND',
     'National- Speech Pathology- ND',
     'SA/WA - Physiotherapy - ND',
     'SA/WA - Telehealth Physiotherapy - ND'
    ))
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server (and many other databases) you need an explicit `CASE` expression:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN appointment_types.name like '%initial%' and 
              appointment_types.category IN (
              'National- Ex Phys- ND',
              'National- Physio -ND',
              'National- OT -ND',
              'National- Speech Pathology- ND',
              'SA/WA - Physiotherapy - ND',
              'SA/WA - Telehealth Physiotherapy - ND'
              )
         THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
```

Comment: isn't sum to calculate the total value right?
I want to count the number of characters that contain the word "initial" and are in the category column.
Then I want to add up the total revenue divided by the number of characters that have the word "initials" in the category column. There is an Incorrect syntax near ')' from your answer.

Comment: i'm using sql server

Comment: but when calculating revenue for both always produce the same value when the results should be different.

`sum(Revenue/ND) as Revenue_ND,`
`sum(Revenue/Home_Care) as Revenue_Home_Care`

Can you tell me why the result is always the same?
where is the fault?

Comment: `sum(CASE`
`WHEN appointment_types.category is not null`
`then invoices.net_amount ELSE 0 END)`
`as Revenue`

`or wrong in this query?`

Comment: The result will still return the same value if I delete this query or change it to explicit 
`sum(CASE` 
`WHEN appointment_types.category is not null` 
`then invoices.net_amount ELSE 0 END)`
`as Revenue`

Comment: @ryan . . . Read the first paragraph of the answer.  The `sum()` with `else 0` should solve the problem, assuming the logic is different in the two expressions and that the data has examples of all the values.

Comment: I have changed all the expressions from count to sum and then 1 else 0 for all but the value that comes out for both expressions is still the same even though the data is different. Even though I deleted one of the "case when" expressions and made another query, the result value between the two expressions remains the same.

Comment: I want to calculate based on the alias of "case when" but only read one condition, other conditions are not read.
is it possible to only need one "case when" but the alias can be calculated?